# Richfaces display image stored as byte[]

Tags: image, richfaces, blob

I am using the < rich:fileUpload > component to input an image, transform it into a byte array and then store it into a mysql database. Is there any component to take that byte array and display as an image?

I'd like to display book.getCover as an image:

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bookDetailsBean.coverUploadListener}"
 stopButtonClass="file-upload-stop-button"
 addButtonClass="file-upload-button"
 id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp" maxFilesQuantity="1"
</rich:fileUpload>


public void coverUploadListener(FileUploadEvent event) {

    UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
    byte[] data = item.getData();
    book.setCover(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In RichFaces 4.x you can display image stored in database as BLOB via

1)

```
<a4j:mediaOutput element="img"
    mimeType="#{bean.imageMimeType}"
    createContent="#{bean.paint}"
    cacheable="false"
    session="false" />
```

2) a image servlet which is reading image from database, and display it in h:graphicImage:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/imageservlet" />
```